# What is the better way of doing queries on Hive date partition?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, hiveql

I'm new to hive and hive data at my work place is partitioned by DATE in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' which I was told is the most common practice. However since the partition is varchar. What would be a better way for finding days for instance greater than 2017-01-01? my query is similar to below:

```
Select fld1, count(*) from tbl1 where date_part >= '2017-01-01' GROUP BY fld1
```

Comment: Cast to date/timestamp or even convert to unixtimestamp for all date comparisons

Comment: Won't casting slow the query down?

Comment: You don't need to cast. Your query looks good.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Your query looks good. Your data format is varchar and since you ensure 2 digits per day and month, you can use `>` `<=`, etc without a problem.

Comment: Major issue I think is me being new to Hive and Hive being slow so I wanted to make sure that I'm not making it worse.